# PHP: How to echo object attributes

Tags: php, meta-tags

How do I echo an object attribute

Is it possible to echo `value='$embed"` of the `$video_data` object below?

My goal is to make a description meta tag for http://perfecthealthmap.com/video-library/1 that populates with this information for the selected video.

```php
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo($video_data->$embed);?>" />
```

Doesn't work.

Below is the information I am trying to echo into the description tag.  Please help.

```php
$video_data .= $embed;
$video_data .= "<br><table width='100%' border=0 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2><tr><td width='50'>URL:</td><td><input type='text' style='font-family: verdana; font-size: 8pt; border: 1px solid #EAEAEA; width: 300px; height: 20px;' onclick='select()' value='http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "'></td></td></tr><tr><td width='50'>Embed:</td><td><input type='text' style='font-family: verdana; font-size: 8pt; border: 1px solid #EAEAEA; width: 300px; height: 20px;' onclick='select()' value='$embed'></td></td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: You may wish to [review the PHP OOP manual pages](http://php.net/language.oop5) and [the language reference in general](http://php.net/langref).

Comment: How about you do `var_dump($video_data)` first and see what that gives you.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a public member variable then you access it via:

```
echo $video_data->embed;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the property is "$embed", you must cast your Object in an associative array and echo your new variable like this

```
echo $ObjectCastInArray['$embed'];
```

unless if the object is from a json_decode, you can directly convert the json string to a associative array, to do that set the second argument in the json_decode function to true

```
json_decode ($yourJsonString, true); // will return an associative array
```

I hope this will help!